# who have permission to refunding a payment of paypal rest api

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using paypal rest api to refund a payment ( for sale payment or captured payment) . https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/refund-payment
But I have a confusion:

- who can make that refunding (seller or buyer)?

Answer (score 0):

Seller can refund the payment by REST API.

Comment: thanks Zhao, so how to paypal know he/she is seller when making a request of funding ?